# Integer promotion with the operator <<

Tags: c, integer-promotion

Similar to the question [Bitshift and integer promotion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482262/bitshift-and-integer-promotion), I have a question about integer promotion when using left bitshifts.

```
unsigned int test(void)
{
  unsigned char value8;
  unsigned int result;

  value8 = 0x12;
  result = value8 << 8;
  return result;
}
```

**In this case, will be the value8 first promote to unsiged int or is it implementation specific?**

> 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators *... 3 Sematics ...*
>   The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
>   that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

It says that the *"The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands."*, but what is here the promotion rule?

I assume that it should be `convert to int if lesser rank than int`, but I can't find it.

I ask this, as one compiler (Renesas nc30wa) doesn't promote to int, so the result is always 0 for my sample.

On this platform, a char is 8 bit wide and int 16 bits.

Comment: If value8 isn't promoted, it's a compiler bug.

Comment: Excactly that is the question, is it a bug or implementation specific?

Comment: @jeb See the edit in my answer, some compiler disable integer promotions by default and documents it in the compiler documentation. You have to look for ISO conformance in the compiler documentation.

Comment: You define `result16` and use `result` - this won't compile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The phrase "the integer promotions" is a *very* specific thing, found in (for C99) section `6.3.1.1 Booleans, characters, and integers`:

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

So assuming your `unsigned char` can be held in an `int`, it will be promoted to an `int`. On those rare platforms where `unsigned char` is as wide as an `int`, it will promote to an `unsigned int`.

This is only changed slightly in C11:

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

If a specific compiler doesn't follow this behaviour, then it's not really conforming. However, given that the compiler you listed is for embedded systems, it's not really surprising.

Many are built for specific purposes and conformance is not always high on the list of requirements. There may be compiler flags that will allow it to more closely conform to the standard.

---

Looking at your *particular* environment, the `M16C Series,R8C Family C Compiler Package V.5.45 C Compiler` has, in section `2.1.4 nc30 Command Line Options`, subsection `f. Generated code modification options`:

> **`-fextend_to_int`, `-fETI`:** Performs operation after extending `char`-type data to the `int` type. Extended according to ANSI standards.

although I suspect `-fansi` is probably a better choice since it covers a few other things as well.

Answer (score 3):

`value8` is promoted to `int`, assuming the conversion rank of `unsigned char` is lower than the conversion rank of `int` (usually the case on most platforms).

The conversion ranks of integers are described in C99 in 6.3.1.1.

Note that some compilers disable the integer promotions rules by default. For example, MicroChip compiler MPLAB C18. Look for ISO conformance in the documentation of your compiler.