# Bit shift operator disregards data size

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I ran across unexpected behaviour while programming in C for an 8-bit AVR microcontroller:
Consider the following:

```
unsigned char a = 0xFF, b = 0xFF;
unsigned short c = ((a>>4)<<8)+b;
printf("%x",c);
```

Where the high order nibble of byte `a` contains bits 8..11 and the byte `b` contains bits 7..0 of a 12-bit value c. The intent of the code was originally to remove the unwanted lower nibble of byte `a`, and then combine `a` and `b` to yield the value of `c`. However later on I realized the code should not work, as `a` is an 8-bit value, and shifting it 8 bits to the left should result in clearing the byte to 0, and a final result of 0x00FF. Instead, the code produces a result of 0x0FFF, as originally intended. The code produces the same result both on the microcontroller (avr-gcc) and on the PC (gcc).  What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: The operands of `>>` are expanded per standard C rules (which I forget at the moment).  But basically `a` is expanded to `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  integral promotion is performed for integral types that have ranks less than the rank of int when shift operators are used. So in this expression

```
(a>>4 )
```

a is converted to type int.

From the C++ Standard

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or
>   wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of
>   int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.

Comment: I guess it promotes to an unsigned int?

Comment: No, values of type char can be placed in type int without looses.

Comment: Just don't bitshift a signed type.

Comment: In this case there is no problem because a is unsigned char and the promoted value is unsigned.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow bitshift of signed integer is implementation-defined behaviour. But thanks, it is interesting to keep in mind that we lose the "unsigned" in the process.

Comment: There is no implementation-defined behaviour because value of a is positive value as a is unsigned character. So the signed bit does not take part in the process.

Comment: @Joky In this case there is no signed types, but OP mentioned char.

Comment: @self unsigned char - it is important.

Comment: @self the promotion ends with a signed type.

Comment: @Joky But the value is positive and the signed bit is equal to zero. So there is no any problem.

Comment: @Joky Can you show where in the OP's code you get a signed value? I don't see it.

Comment: @chux no, Vlad is right, promotion is to an int as long as it can represent ALL values from the promoted type.

Comment: @chux a in converted to signed int. But the promoted value is positive and the sign bit is equal to zero. So there is no any problem.

Comment: @self : the unsigned char is promoted to signed int before the shift. As Vlad says, it is safe because we know that at runtime there can't be any negative value here.

Comment: I have a SO ref that cite the C99 and the C11 standard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203015/integer-promotion-with-the-operator ; here is the quote from C11 "If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.."

Comment: @Joky I see the error of my ways (C11 §6.3.1.1 2) "I will diminish, and go into the West".

Comment: @Joky I was convinced a narrower unsigned would get promoted to unsigned int, and int to int. But instead we get the unsigned char to int, which seems weird.

Comment: @self I agree about narrower `unsigned` to `unsigned`, but C's chapter and verse says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In C, most math on smaller types results in an `int`. You can get the answer you want by casting the result back to `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.