# bitwise shift promotes unsigned char to int

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

The following code:

```
unsigned char result;
result = (result << 4 );
```

Compiled with gcc version 4.6.4 (Debian 4.6.4-2), with the -Wconversion flag results in the warning

warning: conversion to 'unsigned char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]

Why is that?

Comment: Implicit type conversion rules, Bitwise operators auto promotes char to int in C, C++

Comment: here is answer, you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482262/bitshift-and-integer-promotion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the standard says so.  The operands to binary operators
undergo integral promotion, in which anything smaller than an
`int` is promoted to `int`; the results of the operation have
type `int` as well.  And if the original value were, say,
`0x12`, the results would be `0x120`, and assigning this to an
`unsigned char` will cause a change in value.  (The assigned
value will be `0x20`.)  Whence the warning.

EDIT:

From the standard (§5.8 Shift operators): " The operands shall
be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral
promotions are performed.  The type of the result is that of the
promoted left operand."  Unlike other binary operators, there is
*no* effort to find a common type from the two operators: the
result type is that of the left operand, period.  But integral
promotion *does* still occur: the `unsigned char` will be
promoted to `int` (or to `unsigned int` if `int` has a size of
1).

Comment: Am I the only one who is bothered that the warning states "from int to unsigned char"? Doesn't sound like integer promotion, but rather reduction of the numeric literal int to unsigned char. GCC 8.3.0 even designates the numeric literal with the `^` marker, not the `result` variable.

Comment: I "broke my legs" over this freaking "usual arithmetic conversions" multiple times by now. Debugging my code for days and hours to finally reveal this standard over and over again....

Comment: I understand that this is doe for optimization (ints operations run faster than char/short ones) but this causes so much inconvenience and ambiguity that I'm not really sure why standard did't acknowledged this.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `int` value can be larger than can fit in an `unsigned char`.

Think about what will happen when `result` is `255` (i.e. `0xff`). Shifting it left four bits will make it `4080` (or `0xff0`). How will the compiler be able to squeeze that value back into `result`? It can't, so it simply truncates it to `240` (`0xf0`). In other words, the value of the *integer* operation `result << 4` may be be altered.

Comment: This statement, while true, is very vague.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I agree.  I think the gist of the original question is where the `int` came from.

Answer (score 0):

All arithmetic and logical operators perform the "integral promotions" on their arguments. The integral promotions turn types that are smaller than `int` (like `unsigned char`) into `int` or `unsigned int`. You'll see the same thing if you replace `<<` with `+`.

Oh, and the parentheses aren't needed.

Comment: Whether that eliminates the warning or not depends on the compiler.  Even `result <<= 4` involves a narrowing conversion (and of course, the compiler is free to warn about anything it wants anyway).

Comment: @JamesKanze - yup. Removed.