# MISRA error 10.1 Implicit conversion of complex integer

Tags: c, lint, misra, pc-lint

I am writing a code under the MISRA rule. I am getting a MISRA error for the below expression

> check_Val = ( ~( 0x000Fu << Src_Data ) );
>   //where Src_Data is uint8 and check_Val is uint32.

I analyzed the error

> Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 10.1, Implicit conversion of complex integer expression

Since check_Val is `uint32`, the Lf should fit on it. Then why it is giving an error.

Comment: what tool gives you this output ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitshift and integer promotion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482262/bitshift-and-integer-promotion)

Comment: @TomTanner How can it be a duplicate if it doesn't mention MISRA at all?

Comment: You can't know that it "should" fit, since the value of `Src_Data` could be anything up to 255, which would make the shift very large indeed (which doesn't work, and is probably related to the flagging).

Comment: Probably operation is performed promoting elements to `signed int`. That's why `MISRA` is warning you.

Comment: @Lundin the misra rule is getting upset because of implicit promotions, that's why

Comment: Tool gives this out put is PC-lint

Comment: @TomTanner What implicit promotion? There is no implicit promotion in this example, given that int is 32 bits.

Comment: @Lundin: Where is stated that `int` is 32 bits?

Comment: To validate unwind comment you could simply change your Src_Data var with a constant, eg. 7.

Comment: also int != unsigned int

Comment: Firstly uint8 is usually a typedef of unsigned char. Since left shift requires an int value as its right operand you have a type promotion which MISRA would be unhappy about. Secondly what is the word size of the architecture? If you are on an 8-bit platform uint32 would be a type unsigned long but the result of the expression is only 16 bits in size.

Comment: So I looked this up. Disregard the whole implicit promotion issue, this is an artificial problem created by the old MISRA:2004 standard. The tool is correct, regardless of what implicit promotions that actually occur in the code. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule 10.1 is concerned with implicit promotion of integers, by using the MISRA:2004 concept of "underlying type", that is, the intended type of the expression. It was a weird concept which lead to numerous superfluous casts, this has been fixed in MISRA:2012.

The underlying type of your expression is that of the integer literal `0x000Fu`. For integer literals it stated that underlying type is the smallest possible type that is capable of representing the object (see p40-41). So the underlying type of `0x000Fu` will be `uint8_t`, because it can fit in a byte and it is of unsigned type.

Even though, as far as the C language and the compiler are concerned, that integer literal is actually of type `unsigned int` and no promotions will occur. MISRA:2004 doesn't care.

Meaning that you have to cast the operand to `uint32_t` before the operation (to bypass rule 10.1) or cast it to `uint8_t` after the operation (to sate 10.1 and also 10.5 regarding shifts). I suggest you cast it to uint32_t to get rid of the problem.

Fixed code should therefore be

```
check_Val = ~( (uint32_t)0x000Fu << Src_Data );
```

Also, since both operands of a shift operator are integer promoted, the right-hand operator gets implicitly promoted to `int` as well. That promotion can never cause harm, and I'm not sure it is even a MISRA violation, but I suppose it could be causing warnings too. In that case, you would also have to cast the right operand:

```
check_Val = ~( (uint32_t)0x000Fu << (uint32_t)Src_Data );
```

---

I would recommend to use MISRA:2012 if possible, where these rules have been clarified and the "underlying type" concept has been replaced by one which doesn't lead to so many pointless casts.

Comment: It's a way to specify a constant of the appropriate size and value. Though it does apparently create a value of the type `uint_least32_t` rather than `uint32_t`, so I'm not sure MISRA will accept it.

Comment: @EOF In that case it would work, although I would avoid icky macros when possible. They will also cause numerous other MISRA issues, since MISRA doesn't like function-like macros at all, for very sound reasons.