# Bit Shift Operator '<<' creates Extra 0xffff?

Tags: overflow, bit-shift

I am currently stuck with this simple bit-shifting problem. The problem is that **when I assign a short variable any values, and shift them with << 8, I get 0xffff(2 extra bytes) when I save the result to the 'short' variables.** However, for 'long', it is OK. So I am wondering why this would anyhow happen ??

---

I mean, short isn't supposed to read more than 2 bytes but... it clearly shows that my short values are containing Extra 2 bytes with the value 0xffff.

---

I'm seeking for your wisdom.. :)

[This image describes the problem. Clearly, when the 'sign' bit(15) of 'short' is set to 1 AFTER the bit shift operation, the whole 2 byte ahead turns into 0xffff. This is demonstrated by showing 127(0x7f) passing the test but 0x81 NOT passing the test because when it is shifted, Due to it's upper 8. That causes to set Bit15(sign bit) to '1'. Also, Because 257(0x101) doesn't set the bit 15 after shifting, it turns out to be OK.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWFvu.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitshift and integer promotion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482262/bitshift-and-integer-promotion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First, you are doing bit shift operations with signed variables, this may have unexpected results. Use `unsigned short` instead of `short` to do bit shifting, unless you are sure of what you are doing.

You are explicitly casting a `short` to `unsigned short` and then storing the result back to a variable of type `short`. Not sure what you are expecting to happen here, this is pointless and will prevent nothing.

The issue is related to that. `129 << 8` is `33024`, a value too big to fit in a signed `short`. You are accidently lighting the sign bit, causing the number to become negative. You would see that if you printed it as `%d` instead of `%x`.

Because `short` is implicitly promoted to `int` when passed as parameter to `printf()`, you see the 32-bit version of this negative number, which has its 16 most relevant bits lit in accordance. This is where the leading `ffff` come from.

You don't have this problem with `long` because even though its signed `long` its still large enough to store `33024` without overloading the sign bit.

Comment: Ohhhh.... yeah I figured out that I should do the operation with 'unsigned values' but I didn't know that 0xffff was coming from 'pirntf_parameter'! Thank you for sharing your knowledge! ;)