# What integer type does bitwise shift use as shift size?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm trying to find information about shift's size type in C++. For example:

```
int x = 1;

char char_var = 1;
short short_var = 1;
int int_var = 1;
long long_var = 1;
long long long_long_var = 1;

x = x << char_var;  // works
x = x << short_var; // works
x = x << int_var;   // works
x = x << long_var;   // works
x = x << long_long_var;   // works
```

So what type does C++ use for the shift size?

Comment: See [operator coversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I did not find answer there.  `For the built-in operators, lhs and rhs must both have integral or unscoped enumeration type. Integral promotions are performed on both operands.` No info about types

Comment: Does [Bitshift and integer promotion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482262/bitshift-and-integer-promotion) or [Arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) answer your question? "_The type of the result is the type of_ lhs _after promotion_"

Comment: The type of `char_var` is `char`; the types of the operands in `x << char_var` are `int` and  `char`, etc.   If this doesn't answer your question then please try to clarify or re-word your question

Comment: If you read the whole paragraph it explains the conversations in detail

Comment: Why does it matter? In practice, even `char` is big enough to hold the largest shift possible.

Comment: @M.M When we do something like `short x = 1; x++; it converted to x = (short)((int)x + 1)` it means C++ uses int for increment even if we use `short` type. The same question about shift size. Does C++ cast, say `short` to `int` or not?

Comment: It seems you are trying to ask what implicit conversions apply to operands of `<<`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained in [expr.shift]/1: (N4860)

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed

Unlike most other binary operators, the *usual arithmetic conversions* are not performed. The [integral promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)  mean that in your examples the operands of type `char` and `short` are promoted to `int` (on normal systems) and the others are unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

It can be any type: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

In fact the compiler will decide how to cast, and might use intermediate type as it whish. What is garanteed is that if both a and b are positive, the result of a << b is well defined and has the same type as a.

If a or b is negative, the result is undefined and implementation dependent.

Comment: Thank you! So just to make sure: is it safe to say that C++ does not do any implicit conversions apply to operands of <<? Moreover, shift's size type does not affect execution speed of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The standard §8.5.7 says:

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and
> **integral promotions are performed**. The type of the result is that of
> the promoted left operand. The behavior is undefined if the right
> operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of
> the promoted left operand.

So, to me the right operand should be promoted. That means it will be promoted to int, unsigned int, long etc. You can read the whole paragraph with different rules depending on the type of your variable